# Prevent programs from reading files without permission on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

I would like to be able to restrict all programs from accessing my documents and other personal files except a white-list of trusted apps to protect my data from malware.

I know that I can set up Controlled Folder Access to control *write* access, but what about *read* access? What would be the easiest way to achieve this on Windows 10?

Creating a different user seems like a promising idea, but using runas every time I want to edit my files is inconvenient, and using a VM is a little bit overkill. Is there an easier (preferably free) solution?